# Time-complexity with recursion

Tags: time-complexity

Below is an algorithm that find the biggest sum in a triangle. I want to say this algorithm is O(N^2) since the findMax function call can be replaced with a nested for loop looking through each child for each node. However the recursion make me uncertain. So how can I tell the time-complexity of this code with recursion?

```
int maxValue = 0;

void findMax ( Node * n , int sum ) {

if ( n == NULL ) {

    if ( maxValue < sum ) {

        maxValue = sum ;

    }

    return ;

}

findMax (n - > leftChild , sum + n - > value ) ;

findMax (n - > rightChild , sum + n - > value ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int maxValue = 0; // will be executed once so O(1).

void findMax ( Node * n , int sum ) {

if ( n == NULL ) { // Will be executed in every call of function so if considering the function is called C times it is O(C)

    if ( maxValue < sum ) { // will be executed if the previous if is right so O(c')

        maxValue = sum ; // will be exceuted if the previous if is right so O(c')

    }

    return ; // will be executed once so O(1)

}

findMax (n - > leftChild , sum + n - > value ) ; // visiting every left child of each node

findMax (n - > rightChild , sum + n - > value ) ; // visiting every right child of each node 

// so we are visiting every node at least once if we have n node and m connections(edges) between nodes we have:
// O(n+m+C(c'+c'+1))=O(n+m) + O(K)
```